# how to know used row count and column count of excel by using "win32com.client as win32"

Tags: excel, python-2.7, win32com

i want to know how to find the used rows row count and used columns column count by using **win32com.client as win32**

i have written code like this

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('path')
ws = wb.Worksheets("Global")
```

regards,

G Somesh

Answer (score 5):

This should do it when added to your code above:

```
used = ws.UsedRange
nrows = used.Row + used.Rows.Count - 1
ncols = used.Column + used.Columns.Count - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I also use win32com.client, and here is what I use to count the used columns and rows in an Excel. It should would with your current code as well:

```
lastCol = exclsheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lastRow = exclsheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```